# Speed up MYSQL query: lots of value inside the IN operator

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a table with 14000000 postings. When I query table with a select statement, ordered by a datetime field of the postings table, MySQL always uses filesort, resulting in very slow query times (>3 second).  Here's the schema of the story table (simplified):

```
+---------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field               | Type                | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+---------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Id                  | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| parentId            | bigint(20) unsigned | Yes  | MUL | NULL                |                |
| ownerId             | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| updatedAt           | timestamp(6)        | Yes  | MUL | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)|DEFAULT_GENERATED|
| createdAt           | timestamp(6)        | Yes  | MUL | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)|DEFAULT_GENERATED|
| message             | text                | Yes  | MUL | NULL                |                |
| imageUrl            | varchar(255)        | Yes  |     | NULL                |                |
+---------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

I also create index on `ownerId` and `updatedAt`, even create a composite index on `(ownerId,updateAt)` named `ownerId_updatedAt`. Here is the index table:

```
+------------+------------+-------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table      | Non_unique | Key_name          | Seq_in_index | Column_name   | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+------------+------------+-------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| TABLE_NAME |          0 | PRIMARY           |            1 | Id          | A           |    13457024 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| TABLE_NAME |          0 | Id_UNIQUE         |            1 | Id       | A         |    13256858 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| TABLE_NAME |          1 | ownerId           |            1 | ownerId       | A         |      899817 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| TABLE_NAME |          1 | updatedAt         |            1 | updatedAt     | A         |    12862943 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| TABLE_NAME |          1 | ownerId_updatedAt |            1 | ownerId       | A         |      838060 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| TABLE_NAME |          1 | ownerId_updatedAt |            2 | updatedAt     | A         |    13457024 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+------------+------------+-------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
```

And here's the query that takes >3 second to execute.The number of id may be large to about 100.

```
    SELECT  *
        FROM  TABLE_NAME
        WHERE  ownerId IN (id1,id2...,Idn)
          AND  updatedAt < COALESCE(
                    ( SELECT  updatedAt
                        FROM  TABLE_NAME
                        WHERE  storyId = 0),
                    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )
          AND  privacy = 0
        ORDER BY  updatedAt DESC, ownerId ASC LIMIT 20;
```

The result of the explain extended command on this query shows that MySQL is using filesort and using index condition:

```
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------+-----------+---------+--------------------------+----------+----------+--------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys                         | key       | key_len | ref                      | rows     | filtered |Extra                                 |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------+-----------+---------+--------------------------+----------+----------+--------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | TABLE_NAME | range  | ownerId,updatedAt,ownerId_updatedAt   | ownerId   | 8       | NULL                     | 12792    | 5.00     |Using index condition;Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------+-----------+---------+--------------------------+----------+----------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

When I remove the order by part, MySQL stops using filesort. Please let me know if you have any ideas on how to optimize this query to get MySQL to sort and select the data by using indexes. I have already tried a few things such as creating a combined index on all where/order by fields and using `FORCE INDEX(ownerId_updatedAt)` as suggested by a few blog postings, but this didn't work either.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` -- we need to see at least the indexes.

Comment: Do you have the composite `INDEX(storyId, updatedAt)`?

Comment: I don't understand the `COALESCE()`; it seems to be a constant, but it possibly needs to be a correlated subquery?

Comment: > 3 secs is slow? And what is so surprising about that when you want the result rows sorted that MySQL sorts them? (In case you didn't know: The name `filesort` is misleading. It just means `sort` after all.)

Comment: How many rows is your result?  And how many is the privacy=0 excluding?  How long does the query take without the order by?

Comment: also how many records is the `updatedAt <` excluding?

Comment: COALESCE(val1,val2) means Return the first non-null value in a list

Comment: without order by the querying time is < 1 sec.

Comment: I also try adding the composite ```INDEX(storyId, updatedAt)```. However it make the query slower.

Comment: which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: I am using MySQL  8.0.16

Answer (score 0):

As you have said you are using MYSQL  8 that suppoet descending index 
THEN try this Index Check the performance.

```
CREATE INDEX TABLE_NAME
ON Persons (updatedAt DESC,ownerId ASC );
```

[Source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/descending-indexes.html):

Comment: Okay, Wow that did the trick! Thanks a lot. However the query maybe need to be like```CREATE INDEX INDEX_NAME ON TABLE_NAME (updatedAt DESC,ownerId ASC );```

Comment: However I found a problem that when the userId inside IN(u1,...,un) is very few, the query become very slow. Is there any ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: I try to add this index, however it response Error Code: 1060. Duplicate column name 'ownerId'